# Spring Boot requests: to "re-run your application with 'debug' enabled" - how do I?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting a myriad of exceptions trying to run my spring boot project in Eclipse. What they have in common is a "re-run your application with 'debug' enabled" How exactly is this done?

- A maven setting ?
- Use the debugger ?
- A command line argument ?
- A vm argument ?
- A spring application settings ?

I tried a few to no avail. Your assistance much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display auto-configuration report when running a Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47101743/how-to-display-auto-configuration-report-when-running-a-spring-boot-application)

Comment: One of these 2 command line arguments can be used for this purpose: `--debug` or `--trace`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Adding `debug=true` to the `application.properties` or
`debug: true` in the `application.yml`, file should help. You'll get more detailed logging.

Generally, if you want to see more fine-grained log messages from all members of a given package, you can set that by adding a line such as:

`logging.level.<package_name>=<LOGGING_LEVEL>`

for example:

`logging.level.org.springframework.context=DEBUG`

These log messages may be helpful in finding the core of the problem (in this case why a given exception was thrown).

Comment: thanks I just added to the application.yml:

debug: true

Comment: @Igor - For command Line - have Spring Boot Application implement `CommandLineRunner`.  This will pickup the properties from `applications.properties`.

Answer (score 1):

@Joe Doe's answer gives much more details, but in brief:

Add below in your application.yml:

```
debug: true
```

Answer (score -7):

For me its solved my changing port number in `application.properties` in `src/main`

```
server.port=9090
```

Comment: Op asked how he can he run the application with debug enabled, randomly saying that changing the port solved your issue does not help the question asked. Changing the port should only be done if there is a port already in use exception of if you intend to use your application in a different port other than the default