# Spring Active profile setup for existing application

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, kubernetes

Any help much appreciated , I have couple of spring boot application running in aks with default profile , i am trying to change the profile from my deployment.yaml using helm

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "helm-chart.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "helm-chart.name" . }}
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "helm-chart.chart" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "helm-chart.name" . }}
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "helm-chart.name" . }}
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
             
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          env:
          - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
            value: "dev"
```

what i end up is my pod is been put to crashloopbackoff state saying

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.

2022-01-12 12:42:49.054 ERROR 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8207 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

I tried to delete the existing pod and service for the application and did a fresh deploy i still get the same error ..

methods tried :(in all methods docker file is created , pod is created , application in pod is setup to dev profile but the thing is it not able to start the application with the above error , when i remove the profile setting , every thing is workly perfectly fine expect the fact is the application is set to default profile)

1. in docker file :

option a. CMD ["java","-jar","/app.jar", "--spring.profiles.active=dev"]
option b. CMD ["java","-jar","-Dspring.profiles.active=dev","/app.jar"]

2. changed in deployment.yml as mentioned above

ps : i dont have property file in my application on src/main/resources , i have only application-(env).yml files there .

The idea is to set the profile first and based on the profile the application_(env).yml has to be selected

output from helm

```
Release "app" has been upgraded. Happy Helming!
NAME: email-service
LAST DEPLOYED: Thu Jan 13 16:09:46 2022
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 19
TEST SUITE: None
USER-SUPPLIED VALUES:
image:
  repository: 957123096554.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/app
service:
  targetPort: 8207

COMPUTED VALUES:
image:
  pullPolicy: Always
  repository: 957123096554.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/app-service
  tag: latest
replicaCount: 1
service:
  port: 80
  targetPort: 8207
  type: ClusterIP
```

Any help is appreciated , thanks

Comment: Which Kubernetes version are you using? Which base image are you using for your image? Did you try some solutions, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47101743/how-to-display-auto-configuration-report-when-running-a-spring-boot-application)?

Comment: i use alpine docker base image and my k8s version is Client Version: 1.21
Server Version: version.Info Major:"1", Minor:"19+"

Comment: my problem is i have no problem with the pod running with application but with default profile and the problem what i am encountering is when i try to add the default profile , i end up the profile is being set in the pod but it is not starting the application stating "Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address not available"  .. I dont know what is the problem .

Comment: Didn't you specify in `deployment.yaml`, that profile is `test` ? And when it is running with `test` profile (is it?), is tomcat port defined to 8214 in configuration?

Comment: sorry corrected the deployment.yml it is dev profile and not test also added the helm debug output above .

Comment: aws eks --region ${{ parameters.awsRegion }} update-kubeconfig --name myathlon-dev
          cd ./helm-chart && helm upgrade --install  --debug $(servicename) ./ \
          --set image.repository="957123096554.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/$(servicename)" \
          --set service.targetPort=$(targetPort)

Comment: the above is the awshellscript task i use , thanks

Comment: you mentioned once `application-(env).yml` in question and later `application_(env).yml`, see my answer as it's not the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please check what profile the application is using, search for line like this (in log):

```
The following profiles are active: test
```

When I tested with Spring Boot v2.2.2.RELEASE, `application_test.yml` file is not used, it has to be renamed to `application-test.yml`, for a better highlighting of a difference:

```
application_test.yml # NOT working
application-test.yml # working as expected
```

What I like even more (but it is Spring Boot specific), you can use application.yml like this:

```yaml
foo: 'foo default'
bar: 'bar default'

---
spring:
  profiles:
  - test
bar: 'bar test2'
```

Why I prefer this? Because you can use multiple profiles then, e.g. `profile1,profile2` and it behaves as last wins, I mean it will override the values from `profile1` with values from `profile2`, as it was defined in this order... The same does not work with application-profileName.yml approach.

Comment: sorry changed , it is application-(env).yml only and next from the pod logs i see it is mentioned as No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default (this is for application where the above profile changes are made ) but for the pod with above changes to set profile ,the pod is in crashloopback state as it cannot start application , but i see the profile is set to dev but since it cannot start the application with above mentioned error in question

Comment: @Dilu And that error message `The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8214 failed to start.` is from Spring Boot or from k8s? If the latter, there is in Spring Boot log, message saying what port it started Tomcat on. If from Spring Boot itself, that means something is already running on that port already...

Comment: @betilsta , the log is from spring boot  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8207 (http) 2022-01-13 17:31:50.739  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-01-13 17:31:50.740  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.36]Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server

Comment: main] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'tomcatMetricsBinder': java.lang.NullPointerException
2022-01-13 17:31:56.326  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService
2022-01-13 17:31:56.326  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2022-01-13 17:31:56.381  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]

Comment: but the thing here is actually nothing is running their because it is a new pod which i am trying to create

Comment: @Dilu for some reason it is starting with `8207`, check that and compare with default profile... I'm guessing that it is expected to start with `8214` or `8080`...

Comment: since i am was trying with 2 application it was a confusion, both the application we have same problem , it is either 8207 for one application and 8214 for other application ,

Comment: I see. There just needs to be a match (alignment) I would say in between helm and profile. So is it solved now? Keep trying with one only ;-) If those are not running in same pod, you can use same ports too...

Comment: the target port is 8207 for one application everywhere on application.yml , in targetport which is pass to awsshell command from pipeline , as said their is no port issue when i did not pass profile , the port issue happens only when i pass the profile  . because i need to set profile instead of default profile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241040/discussion-between-dilu-and-betlista).

Comment: The issue is we had a hard coded server on the application yml when i changed that , it seems ok , special thanks for Betlista , thanks