# Diagnosis of missing Spring AutoConfiguration class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-sqs

I have a `@SpringBootApplication` with an implementation dependency on `io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure:2.4.4`, which contains the class `SQSAutoConfiguration`.  This autoconfiguration class kicks in at application start-up and constructs a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` bean using the `SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory`

Updating from Spring Boot 2.7.12 to 3.1.2, the SQS processing is no longer working.  Debugging the Spring initialisation process, before and after, and using the `gradle dependencies` tool and the IntelliJ Spring Tool Window, I can confirm that whilst the `spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure` dependency is still present, the `SQSAutoConfiguration` bean is now missing from the Spring context, as a result the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` bean does not get created and so the SQS processing does not happen.

My question is - I have the tools to show me that the auto configure bean is missing after the spring boot version change, but what tools or techniques could I use to determine *why* Spring is not including this bean anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgrade Spring-boot you have to upgrade `io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure` too: Spring-boot 3.x requires Spring-cloud 3.x.

The full compatibility matrix is available at https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws#compatibility-with-spring-project-versions

About the techniques "to determine why Spring is not including this bean anymore", generally speaking, you can examine the [autoconfiguration report](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47101743/685806) generated by Spring in debug mode.